# Visual Studio Code - is there a way to compile ES6 with a built in typescript in VSC, without installing ts compiler separately?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Because I know visual studio code has already comes with typescript built-in it

> It comes with built-in support for JavaScript, TypeScript and Node.js
>   and has a rich ecosystem of extensions for other languages

So i can i use it to compile one file without `npm install typescript` ?

Comment: You need the typescript compiler if you want to compile typescript. In VS Code, the "build" command actually executes "tsc" on the command line. If you don't have tsc installed that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to install Node or TypeScript in order to run your code.

As you quoted, Visual Studio Code has a built-in support for both of them but does not install the run environment. You have to do that by yourself.